# Keep this question, despite all evidence to the contrary

Tags: discussion

https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/12576/recommendation-for-a-computer-based-virtual-instrument-for-an-acoustic-piano-sou

Clearly asking for recommendations, clearly off-topic. BUT this is exactly the sort of thing (I imagine) people will search for. It's a great *hook* question to grab people onto the rest of the site.

For this to work, it becomes doubly-important that the answers address generalities and *how to approach the situation* rather than a stupid list of product names. But I think this question can be more valuable to us *open* rather than *closed.* $.02.

Comment: I agree. I've retracted my vote.

Answer (score 6):

The major justifications against recommendation questions are obsolescence and "too localized" -- I think the case can be made that this is nowadays a well-defined software landscape, and that lots of other people have the same question.

Answer (score 1):

I'd much rather we build a base of people that get here looking for what we're about, than more people having the wrong idea.  Quality over quantity and all that ;) .£0.0124.

Comment: Agreed. But here I think (hope) we can have both. Quality + Quantity is better than either alone.

Comment: Aye, but I think the Idea of an off topic hook question means we'll be catching the wrong fish :/